# if condition does not executed in python after reading values from text file

Tags: python, python-2.x

I dont understand why my if condition is not getting executed in python.`
values inside my text file are

```
 0.000      0 
 0.001      1 
 0.002      2
```

```
f = open(sys.argv[1],"r").readlines()
var=0

for line in f:

    new = f[var].split()

    Time = new[0]
    rev=float(new[1])

    var=var+1

    if 0.001 > Time :

            print " I am here "
```

Comment: Why do you write `f[var].split()` instead of `line.split()`?

Comment: `Time = new[0]` so `Time` is a string. Comparison with floats don't crash in python 2, but don't work either.

Comment: also your code would need a good review. It's just horribly unpythonic

Comment: try: `Time = float(new[0])` for a quickfix. After that, show your code to a python expert for advice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess you should rewrite your code:

```
filename = sys.argv[1]
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        time, rev = map(float, line.split())
        if time < 0.001:
            print("I'm here")
```

You tried to compare string (`Time` variable) with float (`0.001`) - it's wrong. In python 2 it's ok, but always `False`. I recommend you to start using python 3 - you can't compare floats with strings with this version:)

Comment: I was too lazy to answer. Would need more explanation for all the fixes you made, but the code couldn't be better. Comparing strings with floats is wrong because 1) in python 2 it just doesn't work properly/yields false, and in python 3 it explicitly crashes (which is better)

Comment: not to mention that it works in python 2 & 3. The "danger" of providing pythonic code without explanation is seeing a lame answer being accepted (like `Time = float(row[0])`) because OP can quickfix code instead of replacing it by a better one

Comment: use of map is a nice touch.

Comment: map + unpacking. yes.

Comment: I think we should use the cleanest code in answers:) So @user583088 please ask if something seems incomprehensible!